# Vue + Google Analytics + Storage: 'none' (GDRP)

Tags: vue.js, google-analytics

Because GDRP I would like to block cookies for my VUE (nuxt) application and set manually cliendId in Google Analytics.

I searched if there is ready plugin that support such a config and Enhanced Ecommerce. But I haven't found any.

Comment: GA is introducing the idea of `consent` into GA. I would highly suggest reading [the documentation concerning consent](https://developers.google.com/gtagjs/devguide/consent) and seeing if this will work for you.